# When is the Journal of the ACM issued?

Tags: journals

Is there a specific time that the Journal of the ACM is released? Monthly, quarterly, etc? Or does it depend on how many significant papers have been gathered to warrant a new issue? I couldn't find anything specific on their website on this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from their [archive](http://jacm.acm.org/archive.cfm), it seems that since 1994 the Journal of the ACM is issued 6 times a year, so roughly every other month. Until 2006 it was published on odd months. From 2007 on, the schedule seems to be somewhat random, but there are still 6 issues a year (though sometimes one of them is published on the wrong year, as in 2009 and 2010).